# Рассчитать траекторию пули

Tags: разработка-игр, алгоритм, java

Пишу игру и нужно рассчитать траекторию полета пули. Пишу для тачскрина и траектория создается в зависимости от точки касания, позиции пальца на экране, но получается что работает только на вторые 45 градусов из первой половины экрана, [вот как выглядит](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3sJ7TdSRs6o).

А мне нужно, что бы стреляло в любую точку. Помогите, пожалуйста, как рассчитать? Вот как я сделал, что бы оно так летало:

```
angle = Math.atan((y - gameView.shotY) / (x - gameView.shotX)); //позиция начальная - координата косания

x = (int)(x + xSpeed * Math.cos(mAngle));
y = (int)(y + ySpeed * Math.sin(mAngle));
```

Достиг того эффекта, а нужно что бы равномерно летело. Заранее спасибо!

Comment: А силы тяжести (о сопротивлении воздуха вообще молчу) у Вас нет ?

Comment: @avp, там типа вид сверху.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

У меня выдавало странные результаты пока не конвертнул тип данных для x, y к double.
проблема в неявном конвертировании типов в первой формуле. попробуй так:

```
angle = Math.atan ( (double) (y - viewY) / (x - viewX) ) ;
```

**UPDATE**: что, где, когда:

Если я правильно понял то происходит следующее (y - viewY) и (y - viewY) int. При делении результат неявно конвертируется к типу int (здесь и отрезается дробная часть). После чего он неявно конвертируется к типу double для передачи в функцию atan.

проверить можно так:

```
    System.out.println ( 5 / 3 ) ;
    System.out.println ( (double) 5 / 3 ) ;
```

Comment: Черт мужик, респект огромнейший, я с этой проблемой сидел 4 дня, испробовал туеву хучу формул и всяких разных подходов, а нужно было всего лишь переконвертить в дабл результат. Не знаю как тебя благодарить, спасибо тебе огромное!!!!

Answer (score 1):

Помимо `angle = Math.atan ( (double) (y - viewY) / (x - viewX) ) ;` 
надо `(int)` заменить `Math.round`

```
x = Math.round(x + xSpeed * Math.cos(mAngle));    
y = Math.round(y + ySpeed * Math.sin(mAngle));
```